# Muzzle Flash turns on but doesnt turn off with else statement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so this works

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    _muzzleflash.SetActive(true);
    Ray rayOrigin = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0f));
    RaycastHit Hitinfo;
    // cast ray
    if (Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin, out Hitinfo))
    {            
        Debug.Log("hit" + Hitinfo.transform.name);
    }
}
```

but this does not work?

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    _muzzleflash.SetActive(true);
    Ray rayOrigin = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0f));
    RaycastHit Hitinfo;
    // cast ray
    if (Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin, out Hitinfo))
    {            
        Debug.Log("hit" + Hitinfo.transform.name);
    }
}
else
{
    _muzzleflash.SetActive(false);
}
```

why is that?

My thought process was `GetMouseButtonDown(0)` would work when its pressed then call my `_muzzleflash` game object.

And I assume the only way it would not be true is if the mouse click was not being held.

so, pressing down calls this object in the first example. But not does releasing not remove the object, but the object doesnt even show when the mouse is pressed?

ls this object, but releasing does not remove the object?

This is my unity project view btw.

[image: image screenshot]

Comment: When you use the second script, nothing happened?

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi correct

Comment: OK; In second script change `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` to `Input.GetMouseButton(0)`. When you use `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` it calls once and after this it goes to `else...` and muzzle flash disabled. But `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` returns true while you holding left mouse button.

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi that worked. thanks. but why does that work?

Comment: Also I don't know how to mark your comment as "solution".. sort of new to this

Comment: You're welcome, my friend. If you let me, I can post it as an answer and describe completely how it works.

Comment: @ThomasScheer, regarding your question on how to mark the solution, you can *accept* an answer. You cannot mark a comment as a solution. Here is a short explanation if needed: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use `GetMouseButtonDown` instead of `GetMouseButton`

According to the doc of [GetMouseButtonDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html), the function

> Returns true during the frame the user pressed the given mouse button.

While the doc of [GetMouseButton](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButton.html) says that the function

> Returns whether the given mouse button is held down.

This means that in your code, the if is called only one frame, then a few millisecond later, you are in a new frame. Since in the new frame the mouse button has not been pressed (it is still held down but the moment it was just pressed already passed), the else statement is called instead, and stops everything.

To have the desired behaviour (the function must still be true when the mouse is held down), use `GetMouseButton`

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the muzzle flash is only active during the single frame that GetMouseButtonDown return true, and then it's set to false by the `else` statement.

I would actually suggest maybe omitting the `else` statement, and instead adding logic where the muzzleflash gets disabled after it's been active for maybe 100ms or however fast want the muzzleflash to last.

Answer (score 0):

You may use input.getmousebuttonup() to setactive false...
Other wise use invoke method to setactive false